# How to access data in onResponse method through callback in Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm very new to retrofit and android app development in general.
My problem is that I need to extract/return the List "listOfNames" somehow (eventually also "listOfMovies") from the onResponse Method but I could not figure out a way to do it or how to access the callback.

```
    listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();

    Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Base_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    ApiInterface myInterface= retrofit.create((ApiInterface.class));

    Call<MovieResults> call = myInterface.listOfMovies(Category,YOUR_API_KEY,langua,PAGE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResults>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResults> call, Response<MovieResults> response) {
            MovieResults results= response.body();

            List<Result> listOfMovies = results.getResults();
            Result film = listOfMovies.get(1);

            for(int i = 0; i < listOfMovies.size();i++){
                listOfNames.add(listOfMovies.get(i).getTitle());
                Log.d("Movies", listOfMovies.get(i).getTitle());
            };

            String posterlink = poster_url_base_ + "/t/p/w200" + film.getPosterPath();
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(posterlink);


            //Picasso.get().load(myUri).into(myImage);

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResults> call, Throwable t) {


            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
```

The JSON response from the API request looks as follows (example for the first two movies):

```css
  {
  "total_results": 10000,
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 500,
  "results": [ {
    "title": "Chick Fight", "genre_ids": [ 28, 35], "id": 682377, "original_language": "en", "original_title": "Chick Fight", "poster_path": "/4ZocdxnOO6q2UbdKye2wgofLFhB.jpg", "video": false, "vote_average": 5.9, "overview": "When Anna Wyncomb is introduced to an an underground, all-female fight club in order to turn the mess of her life around, she discovers she is much more personally connected to the history of the club than she could ever imagine.", "release_date": "2020-11-13", "vote_count": 38, "popularity": 2182.377, "adult": false, "backdrop_path": "/fTDzKoQIh1HeyjfpG5AHMi2jxAJ.jpg"
  }
  ,
  {
    "title": "Hard Kill", "genre_ids": [ 28, 53], "id": 724989, "original_language": "en", "original_title": "Hard Kill", "poster_path": "/ugZW8ocsrfgI95pnQ7wrmKDxIe.jpg", "video": false, "vote_average": 5, "vote_count": 209, "release_date": "2020-10-23", "overview": "The work of billionaire tech CEO Donovan Chalmers is so valuable that he hires mercenaries to protect it, and a terrorist group kidnaps his daughter just to get it.", "popularity": 1565.855, "adult": false, "backdrop_path": "/86L8wqGMDbwURPni2t7FQ0nDjsH.jpg"
  }
  ,
```

Comment: Do share your json response.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? I couldn't figure your mean?

Comment: I want to access the data after the scope of the onResponse method, i.e. I want to have a List with all the names of the movies available AFTER the scope of the method has ended.

Answer (score 1):

just keep listOfMovies as a filed in your Activity and whenever you want you can extract titles or use it;

```
class ExampleActivity {

    private List<Result> listOfMovies =  new ArrayList();


   ...

   Call<MovieResults> call = myInterface.listOfMovies(Category,YOUR_API_KEY,langua,PAGE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResults>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResults> call, Response<MovieResults> response) {
            MovieResults results= response.body();
            listOfMovies.clear();
            listOfMovies.addAll(results.getResults());
....



    private List<String> getMoviesName(){
        List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfMovies.size();i++){
                listOfNames.add(listOfMovies.get(i).getTitle());
                Log.d("Movies", listOfMovies.get(i).getTitle());
         };
       return listOfNames;
    }
}
```

if you want show names in a recyclerView you just need to create your recyclerView and at the end of onresponse add names to your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this is that the method getMoviesName is only available in the scope of call.enqueue{ scope } and not after that which is where i need the listOfNames...